# add new key to multidimensional array not work

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i get multidimensional array from channel table

```
$sql_channels = get channel sql
$channels = $sql_channels->fetchAll();
```

and i want add video in each channel :

```
foreach($channels as $key=>$channel)
{

$sql_product = get video sql
    $product = $sql_product->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$channels[$key]['videos'] = $product;
}
```

but only first channel have video and after second channel['video'] is empty!!!
out put like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [chanel_title] => test0
            [vedios] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 23 
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [chanel_title] => test1

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [chanel_title] => test2

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [chanel_title] => test3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [chanel_title] => test4

        )
)
```

all channels contain one video . i add 'image' with this method to channel array and work fine but video not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql_channels = get channel sql
$channels = $sql_channels->fetchAll();

$sql_product = get video sql
$product = $sql_product->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// var_dump($product); exit; // uncomment to verify data array

foreach($channels as &$channel_i)
{
    $channel_i['videos'] = $product;
}unset($channel_i);                 

// var_dump($channels); exit; // uncomment to verify output array
```